# Angular2 ng2-bootstrap UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY

Tags: angular, npm, package, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to install ng2-bootstrap with npm but it gives these errors/warnings:

[image: unmet peer dependency]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng2-bootstrap` requires latest releases of Angular 2 libraries (RC5), so you need to update your `package.json` file to download them. It requires RC5 releases of `common`, `compiler`, `core`, `forms` and `platform-server`, but there are more RC5 releases, you can see all of them [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#create-and-configure) and it is highly recommended that you use all the latest releases.

Edit:

I was wrong, the problem seems to be that you are already using RC5 releases, but `ng2-bootstrap` dev team did not publish their version for Angular 2 RC5 release. If you check dependency status for `ng2-bootstrap` [here](https://david-dm.org/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap?type=dev), you can see that it still requires RC4 releases. My advice is to wait until `ng2-bootstrap` team publish an update for RC5, which is expected to happen any day according to [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/pull/864).